# Windows 7, VS2010, .NET and AxMSCommLib

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, com, interop

I have a project that is referencing the AxMSCommLib in VS2010 C#.. My Windows 7 Dev machine doesn't have or can't find this reference. Does anyone have any info on where to get this reference to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSCommLib is an ancient VB6 control.  I don't have it either anymore, even though I installed the VB6 runtime support on this machine.  You'd have to dig up an old VB6 installer somewhere, no idea where to look.  Maybe you can get it from an old machine, copy mscomm32.ocx into your c:\windows\system32 folder and register it with RegSvr32.exe

Time to switch to System.IO.Ports.SerialPort perhaps?