# AxMSMAPI Windows 7 C# .NET Interop Missing

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, com, interop

I have a project that is referencing the AxMSMAPI in VS2010 C#.. My Windows 7 Dev machine doesn't have or can't find this reference. Does anyone have any info on where to get this reference to make it work?

Comment: Is this a dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140914/windows-7-vs2010-net-and-axmscommlib

Comment: no, diff com objects. One is AxMSMAPI and on is AxMSCommLib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact same answer as your other question, this time it is msmapi32.ocx.  Review this [Support Statement article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx) for more details, note that these controls are in the "supported, but install yourself" block.